# Which songs in my iTunes library are DRM protected?

Tags: itunes, drm

Is there an easy way to obtain a list of all songs in my iTunes library that are protected by DRM?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a smart playlist and use "kind contains protected" as the first rule.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see this information **without** excluding the other songs, you can modify the view options

[image]

and add the "Kind" information column.

[image]

In this column you will see the information you need.