# Is there still iTunes plus upgrade for DRM'ed music?

Tags: itunes, drm

Thanks to the tip [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/which-songs-in-my-itunes-library-are-drm-protected), I was able to make a smart playlist containing all the DRM encumbered music in my iTunes library.

I remember in the past there was an offer from iTunes Plus that lets you pay a fee to "upgrade" your DRM'ed songs to unprotected ones.

Does this still exist? How do I get non-DRM'ed versions of these songs nowadays?

Thanks!

BTW, I am running iTunes 10.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 4):

Open up iTunes. Go to the iTunes Store. Click on the iTunes Plus link at the bottom of the navigation window:

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but got a message saying I have already upgraded to iTunes plus, and no other options. However, I can obviously see DRM'ed songs in my library. What should I do???