# Checking iTunes collection for DRM

Tags: itunes-store, drm

How can I check which songs or videos that I purchased from the iTunes Store have DRM restrictions?

All of the mobile OSes are very impressive to me at the moment, and I'm thinking about trying a non-iOS device again. I want to know now the impact it has on my Apple-sourced music collection though.

Is there a date cut-off for purchases when items went DRM free?

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/delete-old-drm-copies-of-itunes-music-and-download-drm-1546445214

Comment: @cksum haha, that's so simple I'll delete this if you don't answer it.

Comment: Leave it up for anyone else that might need it in the future. @Tetsujin go ahead, it's all yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delete Old DRM Copies of iTunes Music and Download DRM-Free Versions**

If you purchased any music from iTunes between 2003 and 2009, you downloaded tracks with DRM ([Digital Rights Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)) in them. Apple's long since removed the DRM, but you might not have. Wired shows how to update your music library with the new, DRM-free versions.

The process here is pretty simple, but if you're anything like me, you never bothered to actually do it:

- Before starting, make sure you are signed in to the iTunes Store [Store menu] & can see the columns for **Kind** & **iCloud Download** in your **Songs** view in iTunes, then sort by **Kind**
  Scroll down to find 'Protected AAC audio file' as a Kind - those are the ones you need to replace.

[image: iTunes]

1. In iTunes, select iTunes > Preferences and click the "Store tab"
2. Make sure "Show iTunes in the Cloud Purchases" is checked and close the Preferences panel
3. Click on the cloud icon in your list view and make sure all your purchases are there (note which songs are here and do not delete anything in step 5 that isn't available for download)
4. Now, delete the old DRM versions by sorting by "Kind" in the list view (if it's not there, go to View > Show View Options and select it)
5. Scroll down to see if any tracks are listed as "Protected AAC audio file." That's the DRM music you need to replace. If you can download it again from iTunes with the cloud icon, you can delete the DRMed version

Once you run through the process of deleting those songs you can download them from the cloud at any point, DRM free. This has been around for a while, but if you haven't grabbed those DRM free versions, now's as good a time as any.

Source: Lifehacker [Delete Old DRM Copies of iTunes Music and Download DRM-Free Versions](http://lifehacker.com/delete-old-drm-copies-of-itunes-music-and-download-drm-1546445214)

Also see - [Which songs in my iTunes library are DRM protected?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/which-songs-in-my-itunes-library-are-drm-protected?rq=1)

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  I was able to download the songs again, but they came in with DRM again.