# Can't use iTunes songs in iMovie 10? -"protected & unavailable"

Tags: itunes, music, imovie

I can't seem to use any of my purchased songs in iTunes - basically, any of my iTunes music - in an iMovie project.

I go to the music/iTunes tab in a project and I just get a notice that x-number of songs are protected and unavailable. Does this mean that now I literally can't use any music I bought in iMovie? I was working on just a personal video and have been able to use all the songs in my iTunes library in past versions of iMovie.

I can't find an answer about it anywhere.

Comment: as a temp solution import into garageband export and then import into iMovie.  This should work.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/149147/checking-itunes-collection-for-drm/149170#149170

Answer (score 1):

Do you have itunes Radio? We had a similar problem that we had downloaded a song through iTunes radio. The song is on the computer, but since we didn't purchase it we can't use it in any other program other than iTunes. We had to delete the song, and then purchase it through the store.